# Pointcloud and RGB Image alignment on RealSense ROS

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, ros, point-clouds, realsense

I am working on a dog detection system using deep learning (Tensorflow object detection) and Real Sense D425 camera. I am using the Intel(R) RealSense(TM) ROS Wrapper in order to get images from the camera.

I am executing "roslaunch rs_rgbd.launch" and my Python code is subscribed to "/camera/color/image_raw" topic in order to get the RGB image. Using this image and object detection library, I am able to infer (20 fps) the location of a dog in a image as a box level  (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)

I will like to crop the PointCloud information with the object detection information (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)
and determine if the dog is far away or near the camera. I will like to use the aligned information pixel by pixel between the RGB image and the pointcloud.

How can I do it? Is there any topic for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that just with xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax you cannot calculate the distance because it can be a very small dog or a very big dog and the difference will be big, right?

Comment: @Albondi You did not understand the question, with (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) I get the bounding box of the RGB image where the dog is located. Then I will like to analyze this box with the point cloud in order to determine the distance

Comment: why not use the bounding box you got from RGB on depth image ??

Comment: I am after the same, still couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel publishes their python notebook about the same problem at: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/jupyter/notebooks/distance_to_object.ipynb

What they do is as follow :

1. get color frame and depth frame (point cloud in your case)
   [image]
   [image]
2. align the depth to color
   [image]
3. use ssd to detect the dog inside color frame

[image]
[image]

4. Get the average depth for detected dog and convert to meter

```sh
depth = np.asanyarray(aligned_depth_frame.get_data())
# Crop depth data:
depth = depth[xmin_depth:xmax_depth,ymin_depth:ymax_depth].astype(float)

# Get data scale from the device and convert to meters
depth_scale = profile.get_device().first_depth_sensor().get_depth_scale()
depth = depth * depth_scale
dist,_,_,_ = cv2.mean(depth)
print("Detected a {0} {1:.3} meters away.".format(className, dist))
```

Hope this help